# Construction of "Third Conditional" sentences

Tags: conditional-constructions

I have read English grammar lesson about "Third Conditional" and got confused. Let's consider the following two sentences:

> 1. If I **would have bought** the house, I would have got a mortgage.
> 2. If I **had bought** the house, I would have got a mortgage.

Pattern which has been used to make the first sentence is considered to be wrong, meanwhile the second one is considered as a correct one. So why in the first half of the sentence it is incorrect to use **would**, meanwhile in the other half it is OK to use it?

Also is there a general pattern for construction of **"Third Conditional"** sentences?

Comment: Which "grammar lesson" did you read?

Comment: See Wikipedia on [The conditional in English](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences), especially the part about using *will* and *would* in conditional clauses.

Comment: Like almost all "Why?" questions about language, the answer is "Because that is how it is". There _is_ no other answer.